# How to list alternative certificate subject name

Tags: curl

I get this error:

```
curl https://a.b.c.de/
SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'a.b.c.de'
```

How to list all valid names of `a.b.c.de`?

AFAIK these are CN plus "alternative certificate subject name"

I would like to know which names would be valid.

A solution with curl would be nice, but any linux tool could be used, too.

Comment: Do you need to use curl?

Comment: @Rob I updated the question.

Comment: AFAICT `curl` has no option to show the server's cert.  To see the server cert I would use `openssl s_client -connect a.b.c.de:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -text`.  Historically some clients would allow a hostname match against the CN but the official method is to match only against the names listed in the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) field.

Answer (score 4):

With the help of user ottomeister I found a solution to get the *Subject Alternative Name*

Command:

```
openssl s_client -connect a.b.c.de:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | \
    openssl x509 -inform pem -text | grep -A1 "Subject Alternative Name"
```

Result:

```
 X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
     email:info@a.b.c.de, DNS:other.c.de, IP Address:93.184.216.34
```